# Exclude footer, header and navigation from Lucene indexing?

Tags: php, html, lucene

I'm working on an old, large site made ages ago by another developer. He has used Lucene as the engine for the site search, indexing all pages in their full HTML form: (Some parts omitted for clarity)

```
$this->index = Zend_Search_Lucene::open($path);
$html = file_get_contents($document["path"]);
$doc = Zend_Search_Lucene_Document_Html::loadHTML($html);
$doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::Text('url', $document["path"]));
$this->index->addDocument($doc);
```

The problem is that the site navigation, footer and header get indexed as well - doing a search for "copyright" returns every single page.

Is there some switch I could flip when indexing full HTML content? I have no prior experience with Lucene but indexing the whole page seems pretty useless if there is no way to exclude the elements present on every page. Or should I just rewrite the search to just index the content from the database instead of cycling it through HTTP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to [Delve inside the Lucene indexing mechanism](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-lucene/), I would say that it is prudent to just store the textual information in lucene rather than the entire HTML.

If you have direct database access, storing the column data as "Fields" will provide you with a much fine grained control over search (For example, performing boolean and range queries in those fields).

Comment: So it seems, using fields straight from the database is clearly the way to go. Thanks for the advice and the very enlightening link!